# Plotting Multiple lines on the same figure From Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

After getting dates and values from my database I want to graph this with two lines one representing pure_results and another representing applied_results. I want to plot these dates on the same figure.

I tried plotting the data on the same figure and it worked for a little bit using the code below.

I have two tables in which I get time_stamp which is a date along with SUM(Correct) which is the value I plot and then GROUP BY time_stamp causing duplicate dates to merge into one and sort the data (into two different lists).

```
def correct_graphs(user_id):
    dates_pure = []
    correct_pure = []
    dates_applied = []
    correct_applied = []
    sql_pure = "SELECT time_stamp,SUM(Correct) FROM pure_results WHERE user_id = ? GROUP BY time_stamp"
    sql_applied = "SELECT time_stamp, SUM(Correct) FROM applied_results WHERE user_id = ? GROUP BY time_stamp"
    cursor.execute(sql_pure, [(user_id)])
    for a in cursor.fetchall():
        dates_pure.append(a[0])
        correct_pure.append(a[1])
    cursor.execute(sql_applied, [(user_id)])
    for b in cursor.fetchall():
        dates_applied.append(b[0])
        correct_applied.append(b[1])
    plt.plot(dates_pure, correct_pure, label="Pure Progess")
    plt.plot(dates_applied, correct_applied, label="Applied Progess")
    plt.xlabel("Dates of Maths Question Attempted")
    plt.ylabel("Questions Correct")
    plt.title("Comparsion of Correct Progess")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

However after some of the dates change in two tables I expected the output to be x-axis plotted in date order however my actual result is [matplotlib graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fNaI.png)

Example Data :

```
dates_pure = ['2019-03-25', '2019-03-26', '2019-03-30', '2019-04-02', '2019-04-03']
correct_pure = [4, 6, 5, 6, 8]
dates_applied= ['2019-03-25', '2019-03-26', '2019-03-27', '2019-03-30', '2019-04-05']
correct_applied = [6, 3, 4, 10, 5]
```

I need a way of merging the two lists and sorting them in chronological order to fix the x-axis and then be able to plot pure_results and applied_results as two separate lines or being able to plot the two line simultaneously

Comment: you need to sort the values before ploting

Comment: It seems there's a duplicated date for 2019-03-30. Why is that the case? Possibly you'll need to group them. Not sure if you need a mean or the sum, though. Else, your data isn't ordered

Comment: I think you need to specify your question a bit better and maybe sort the values out as makaros said

Comment: The dates are in order in there separate lists but, when plotted they aren't in order and if I sort the lists together then I can't plot the two lines properly. If I ordered the data in one list then i can't plot the values properly.